# Check if the node if exists in a SQL Server xml column

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a column in my SQL Server table with this XML value :

```
<ValidTestResult version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
  <item CarType="پراید" SystemType="2" model="1382">
    <count>7777</count>
  </item>
  <item CarType="1" SystemType="2" model="1382">
    <count>100</count>
  </item>
  <item CarType="1" SystemType="2" model="1380">
    <count>100</count>
  </item>
</ValidTestResult>
```

I want to check if a node exists, update the value of count. I do that using this code:

```
UPDATE InquiryStatus
SET TotalCarburetorResult.modify(N'replace value of 
(/ValidTestResult/item[@model=("1382") and @CarType=("پراید")]/count/text())[1] with ("7777")') where id=27
GO

UPDATE InquiryStatus
SET TotalCarburetorResult.modify(N'insert <item CarType="پراید" SystemType="2" model="1382"><count>100</count></item> into (/Result)[1]')
```

As you can see my code inserts and updates the value, but I need something else:
I want to check if the node exists, then update the value count and if doesn't exist, it should insert a new node. How can I check if the node exists?

For example a node with this attributes:

```
<item CarType="1" SystemType="2" model="1382">
```

Comment: Do you want to check on **all** three attributes? Or does one of them suffice?

Comment: @marc_s Yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TotalCarburetorResult.exist(N'/ValidTestResult/item[@model=("1380") and @CarType=("پراید")]') 
FROM InquiryStatus 
WHERE id = 27
```